# Script populates last column (instead of first one) in a new row

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a frustrating problem with php template for a page in Wordpress. It displays member's images/info in a 4-column grid. It works fine until the last row, which only has one image/member, but that member's image is populating the 4th column instead of the 1st leaving a 3-column gap before it.

Code:

```
<div class="row">

<?php
$thisrow=1;
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
'order'             => 'ASC',
'post_type'         => 'teamposts',
'post_status'       => 'publish',
'meta_query'        => array (
        array (
            'key'   => 'team_type',
            'value' => 'Staff',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
),
); 
$theseposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $theseposts as $thispost ) : setup_postdata( $thispost );
if ($thisrow==5) {
    $thisrow=0;
    echo '</div><div class="row">';
}
$large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($thispost->ID), 'large' ); 
echo '<div class="col-md-3 team-member" style="text-align:center;"><a href="/about/board-staff/?'.get_post_field('post_name',$thispost->ID).'">';
if (strlen($large_image_url[0])) {
    echo '<img alt="'.get_the_title($thispost->ID).'" src="'.$large_image_url[0].'" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:16px;">';
} else {
    echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/grey.jpg" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:16px;">';
}
echo '</a><h5 class="member-name"><a href="/about/board-staff/?'.get_post_field('post_name',$thispost->ID).'">'.get_the_title($thispost->ID).'</a></h5><div class="member-position" style="margin-bottom:4px;">'.get_field('job_title',$thispost->ID).'</div><div><a href="mailto:'.get_field('email_address',$thispost->ID).'">'.get_field('email_address',$thispost->ID).'</a></div><br /><br /></div>';
$thisrow++;
endforeach; 

?>

</div>
```

Any suggestions in how to make it populate the 1st column (and make sure next ones do the same/next)? Thanks in advance!

Screenshot is here https://s1.postimg.org/9sfjesenr3/team.png

Comment: Show the HTML code generated for the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $thisrow=0 could be the issue. It looks like you're actually putting 5 columns on the 2nd row when you mean to put 4. Try setting $thisrow=1 instead and see if that helps. Also what's the css for col-md-3? Is it pulling to the right or left?

Comment: Thank you! It took me a minute to get back to it, but  $thisrow=1  did the trick. Much appreciated!